# List all the csv files containing specific subtring

Tags: python, python-3.x, read.csv

I have +200 12MB CSV files and I have to search through all of them to list all the CSV containing a specific substring. Nevertheless, something is wrong with either loop or how I read the file because no results are printed and I have no idea how to fix it.

I have tried other stackoverflow solutions but none has worked, unfortunately.

```
import csv, os, glob
 
path = r'C:/Users/me/Desktop/csvfolder/*csv'
keyword = '261892'
 
for Tname in glob.glob(path):
    #print (os.path.abspath(Tname))
    #read csv, and split on "," the line
    csv_file = csv.reader(open(os.path.abspath(Tname), "r",encoding= 'UTF-8'), delimiter=",") 
    for row in csv_file:
        if keyword == row[0]:
              print (os.path.abspath(Tname))
```

Comment: Is python mandatory for your solution or is it just important to find the file containing the substring? Have you tried debugging your problem? How does your solution fail?

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed . It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing. (PL: powodzenia)

Comment: you check only in first column, and only if it is exactly `261892` but it may have other text with `261892` (or spaces) - so maybe you should check `if keyword in row[0]` to check substring. But if you would use `print()` to display `row[0]` then maybe you would see why it doesn't match `keyword`. For test you could start with one small file - so you could simply see all values on screen

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the type of 'csv_file' variable? If it became a list, I assume there won't be any rows or columns, but list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

You might what to check for blank rows by adding 'if row:' to your code:

```
    for row in csv_file:
        if row:
            if keyword == row[0]:
                  print (os.path.abspath(Tname))
```

I tested it with a set of 80 csv files of my own and got it to work.